# Can I use "way how to" to express a method of doing something?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I always thought that this phrase is wrong. That I can use either "*the way to* do something" or "*how to* do something". However, I find the phrase *way how to* very often in various places and that puts me in doubt whether this is correct or not.

Can you think of a proper usage example or are a lot of people just wrong when they use the phrase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People do say "the way how to", but it's pointlessly redundant. I'd say simply "the way to" or "how to".

Example: "a way how to learn" is technically grammatically correct, but awkward. "How" is an adverb, which is modifying "to learn". So it's valid, just unnecessary.

Comment: "...a great way how to learn...": is 'way' redundant here? Or, is 'how' redundant?

Comment: Thanks Jay! Is it gramatically correct?

Comment: @David Stula. Yes, it is. And you can use it without asking yourself if it is: it is real English.

Comment: Actually, I cannot upvote anything until I have at least 15 reputation.

Comment: @Regis I would say "... a great way to learn." You cannot say "... a great how to learn" because "how" is an adverb and you cannot use an adjective ("great") to modify an adverb. If you want to use the word "great" you need some noun for it to modify. "Way" works fine. You could say "method", "technique", etc.

Comment: @David Stula - Do you want to say 'I cannot upvote nothing ...'? Don't you?

Comment: @RégisRoux Why would I want to say that?

Comment: I think "a way how to learn" is technically grammatically correct, but awkward. "How" is an adverb, which is modifying "to learn". So it's valid, just unnecessary. Also, we usually -- but not always -- put adverbs after the verb. We'd be more likely to say "a way to learn quickly" than "a way quickly to learn". But both would be correct.

Comment: @Jay - thank you Jay. You had been very nice in  answering my comment.

Comment: Well, Jay's last comment answers what I wanted to know. And something extra :) Thanks a lot. I'll vote up when the system lets me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Czenglish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czenglish) book by Don Sparling, the construct *This is the **way how to** do something* is almost a signature phrase of Czech English and it is widely used by anybody from college professors to total beginners. Nevertheless, it is not standard English. The correct thing to say is either *This is the **way to** do something* or *This is **how to** do something*.

Source and some usage examples: http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projekty/lexdb/czeng.cgi?direct=264

Comment: This does not answer the question. “Way to do” is not incorrect, first of all; and moreover, how Czech people do or do not have problems with this phrase is not relevant to the English language.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit the 'incorrect' statement. But I still think it is relevant. It provides a possible explanation how the phrase appeared. Additionally, the name of the OP sounds Czech, so he may be interested in this.

Comment: I tried again. Better?